# React native background state show floating window button

Tags: android, react-native

So I need my app that has a switch, which when turned on, should create a FAB. This should then run like a background service, over all other apps, after the main activity/app is closed. So anywhere I touch the FAB, it should be clickable,moveable and should draw over all apps.

work on react native